# My code for creating render buffer does not work on Apportable SDK

Tags: opengl-es, apportable

On iOS works fine but on apportable not, maybe I did something wrong:

```
    GLsizei height = _glview.drawableHeight;
    GLsizei width = _glview.drawableWidth;

    if (pickingFramebuffer == 0) {
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &pickingFramebuffer);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pickingFramebuffer);

    if (pickingColorRenderbuffer == 0) {
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &pickingColorRenderbuffer);
    }
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, pickingColorRenderbuffer);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, pickingColorRenderbuffer);

    if (pickingDepthRenderbuffer == 0) {
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &pickingDepthRenderbuffer);
    }
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, pickingDepthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, pickingDepthRenderbuffer);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Framebuffer status: %x", (int)status);
    }
```

Log:

```
Framebuffer status: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**
If I will add to everyone function and opengl directive OES, Framebuffer status will be **0**

**EDIT 2:** OK, it's a bug https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bug in software and currently it does not has any solution. Link on bug report https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: There is currently a hack in Apportable to make integrating iOS opengles code easier with Android's expectations for opengles. The first framebuffer and renderbuffer you make return the default framebuffer and renderbuffer (the default has id 0). If this code is for your main rendering window, try not checking for 0. If this is a secondary renderbuffer, make sure that your main renderbuffer is set up first. It is normally straightforward to work around these issues once you understand that Apportable is giving you back the default framebuffer and most of your setup code isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again. With this code I'm trying create second renderbuffer, currently no luck. Returns 0 or GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT. If you will have time, could you please provide some working version?